# How should I report a bug concerning the live USB/DVD image?

Tags: live-usb, 19.10

This one is tricky, since I can't just identify the package and file a bug concerning the package, because it's not a problem concerning its behaviour in a regular desktop environment.

Actually the problem is that the live system keeps /var/crash and /var/log mounted on the support. Not quite read-only any more huh ?

Because of this :

- The live image is modified (failing further checksum-based integrity checks one would want to make before booting)
- It's not possible to load to RAM and eject

Actually it's possible to load to RAM and eject (what's impossible with Linux after all ?), but that requires more steps :

```
# umount /var/crash
# fuser -m -k -TERM /var/log ; umount /var/log # repeat until it works (usually once is enough)
```

And then eject, the usual way, e.g. from the Nautilus interface.

But it's not supposed to be a place to report bugs here, hence my question : how shall I report ?

**EDIT :** I found out that persistence is enabled by default. One has to pass the `nopersistent` parameter at boot to prevent the live system from creating an additional r/w partition on the support. This is annoying...

Comment: A real Ubuntu Live .iso really is read-only. You cannot accidentally create a new squashfs image, and write it to the USB, except through a spectacular comedy of errors. Perhaps you enabled persistence?

Comment: When I say the image has been modified, I mean the image I dd'd to the USB support. If I check like this : `dd if=/dev/my_usb_stick count=imgblocknum | shasum -a 256`, I don't get what I should get. In the present case (current 19.10 live image), imgblocknum is 4812192 blocks. I tried before booting it, and it was giving me the correct value. No persistence is activated, I only passed the "locale=fr_FR.UTF-8" and "toram" parameters to the kernel. I tried without passing anything, and the problem is the same. Anyway, just try for yourself and you will see. I had no problems with the 19.04 image

Comment: @user535733 : It turns out persistence must be enabled by default. I tried on qemu by crafting a disk image containing the live image followed by 1 GiB of zeroes to simulate my USB stick, and had the same behaviour. Passing the `nopersistent` parameter prevents the live image from creating an additional r/w partition on the support.

Comment: I was just bitten by this. I used a USB drive as boot medium, wrote the .iso, and added an additional partition (sda5) to use as a writeable location. But, when booting, both /var/crash and /var/log are mounted to sda5. I didn't even know you could have multiple mount points to the same partition :) Anyway, install logs persist from one boot to the next...

Comment: Actually, with further research, it looks like the installer _created_ sda5 and just started using it automatically. Frustrating!

Comment: @bitsmack Frustrating indeed ! It shouldn't be like that, read-only should obviously be the default behaviour, and persistence should only be activated explicitly or when a persistence partition is detected on the same device as the live image. This idea of automatic partitioning from a live usb is atrocious. I talked to the developer, he didn't want to discuss any other option than his own, with no explanation, no argument except that he "strongly wanted" this. So yeah, better use another image, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that reporting a bug in the `casper` package is the way to go when reporting bugs that are specific to the live image.